# How to validate an AJAX form which uses CTools?

Tags: forms, ajax, chaos-tool-suite

I have a form which opens in a modal CTools window. The forms submits perfectly, but when I try to use the my_form_validate() function, it never goes to that function, it always go directly to my_form_submit() function? I have tried to "uncode" the CTools modal windows example provided with the module, but I am not able to decipher it.

Comment: How did you create the form? Is it created with a my_form() function? If so, it should validate through my_form_validate().

Comment: It is rendered with AJAX: return drupal_get_form('mymodule_form'); inside the callback function, and I have a my_module_my_form function as usual. The same form works perfectly if it is called outside the AJAX function, directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just discovered that I had mistyped mymodule_my_form_validate as my_module_my_form_validate. Your reply has made me look into the function and now it works perfectly. Somehow I thought the method was much more convoluted as involved AJAX. Sorry, this is very embarrasing. In any case, your reply saved me a lot of time.